# Create new Pandas boolean df based on values from list

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this df:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
A     B     B    A
B     C     C    D
D    null   D   null
```

And a list

```
list1 = ["A","B","C","D"]
```

How do I create a new df with the boolean representation of the values of the list as first column if the value is in the old df columns?

Expected output:

```
list1 col1 col2 col3 col4
  A    1    0    0    1
  B    1    1    1    0
  C    0    1    1    0
  D    1    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
res = pd.DataFrame(index=list1, columns=df.columns).fillna(0)

res.loc[:, :] = df.stack().reset_index().pivot_table(index=0, columns="level_1", aggfunc="count").notna().astype(int).droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

   col1  col2  col3  col4
A     1     0     0     1
B     1     1     1     0
C     0     1     1     0
D     1     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially crosstab:

```
df.melt().groupby('value')['variable'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
variable  col1  col2  col3  col4
value                           
A            1     0     0     1
B            1     1     1     0
C            0     1     1     0
D            1     0     1     1
```